Cause of "The Server Appears To Be Down"
I just migrated my WordPress multisite to a new host (AlmaLinux 9).  It WAS working fine...but I must have done something.  Any attempt to reach any page of the hosts results in a wordpress formatted message:
Offline
The server appears to be down, or your connection isn't working as expected. Please try again later.

I've tried to undo any changes but can't figure it out.  I disabled all plugins, but still the same.  The httpd error and access logs don't indicate any problems.
What is going wrong here?  How do I figure this out
